# Summing values in a List. Could I be doing this more efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, list

I have a list of Fact objects. Each object has a Date field (reportingDate) and a long field (numberSaved). There are several results for each reportingDate. I'm trying to get a sum of all numberSaved values for each reporting date. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
private static List<Fact> sumFacts(List<Fact> facts) {
    List<Fact> summedFacts = new ArrayList<Fact>();

    for (Fact fact : facts) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Fact sumFact : summedFacts) {
            if(sumFact.getReportingDate().equals(fact.getReportingDate())) {
                found = true;
                sumFact.setNumberSaved(sumFact.getNumberSaved() + fact.getNumberSaved());
            }
        }            
        if (!found) summedFacts.add(fact);
    }        
    return summedFacts;
}

public class Fact {
    String reportingDate;
    long numberSaved;

    public String getReportingDate() {
        return reportingDate;
    }
    public void setReportingDate(String reportingDate) {
        this.reportingDate = reportingDate;
    }
    public long getNumberSaved() {
        return numberSaved;
    }
    public void setNumberSaved(long numberSaved) {
        this.numberSaved = numberSaved;
    }
}
```

For each item in the original list, it iterates through the new list looking for a matching Date. If it finds an object with a matching date, it adds its numberSaved value to it. If it makes it through the whole list without finding a matching date, it adds itself to the new list.

Is there a more efficient way that I could be summing the values into a list of Fact objects with unique dates?

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I need to maintain the order of the items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping your facts in a `List` and iterating over it (producing an O(n^2) complexity), you could store them in a map form the reporting date to the fact object, giving you an O(n) complexity:

```
private static List<Fact> sumFacts(List<Fact> facts) {
    Map<String, Fact> summedFacts = new HashMap<Fact>();

    for (Fact fact : facts) {
        summedFact = summedFacts.get(fact.getReportingDate());
        if (summedFact == null) {
            summedFacts.put (fact.getReportingDate(), fact);
        } else {
            summedFact.setNumberSaved(summedFact.getNumberSaved() + fact.getNumberSaved());
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<Fact>(summedFacts.values());
}
```

Comment: His `date` is actually just a `String`, but otherwise this is exactly what I was about to propose, and is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using the date as a key and then including the whole object as the value. I forgot to mention that I had to maintain order, so I used a LinkedHashMap instead. Will that affect the performance gains from using a Map?

Comment: AFAIK, it will have some minor performance penalty (compared to a simple `HashMap`), but the order or magnitude (O(1) for checking if a key is in the map, O(n) for the the method) should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this could be faster is if both lists were sorted by some key (most likely your date that you are using).  Checking for the existence of an object in an unsorted list is `O(n)`, and you are doing this for every element of another list, making the problem `O(m * n)`.

This shows that your solution is as efficient as it can be without presorting lists.

The most you can improve on is to use List.add(int, Object) so that it inserts the item to the front of the list so that it is not looped over again.

Answer (score 1):

You could greatly increase performance by ussing a `HashTable` for `summedFacts` (read more on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

You would have your date converted to string and use it as Key of the `HashTable`. The value of the `HashTable` will hold the sum for the `Fact` objects with the same date.

HashTable access is instant (O(1)) therefore this solution will lead you to an O(n) implementation instead of your O(n*m) one.

For example:

```
private static HashTable<string, Fact> sumFacts(List<Fact> facts) {
HashTable<string, Fact> summedFacts = new Hashtable<string, Fact>();

for (Fact fact : facts) {
    // Check if the item with this date is already added to the HashTable. If not, then add it
    if (summedFacts.get(sumFact.getReportingDate()) == null) 
                  summedFacts.put(fact.getReportingDate(), fact); // add the value to the HashTable.
      else {
            // If the date is already there, than perform adition. 
            currentFact = summedFacts.get(fact.getReportingDate()); 
            currentFact.setNumberSaved(fact.getNumberSaved() + currentFact.getNumberSaved());
        }
    }            
}        
return summedFacts;
```

}